# the sides of my activity change

Tags: android

Every time I work with the emulator the app is fine, but when I send it to its sides it always turns upside down and everything on the right goes to the left and everything on the left goes to the right. can you please try to help me figure out what do I need to do in order to make this stop, so the app in my phone will be like the emulator?

example:
[the activity in my phone](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w7uR6.png)

Example:
[the activity in the emulator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opxfW.png)

here is the xml code

```
<LinearLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="settings"
        android:textColor="#0000FF"
        android:textSize="50dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:textStyle="italic"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="choose your level"
        android:textColor="#3300FF"
        android:textSize="30dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">


    <RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"

        >

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/begginer"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="begginer"
            android:textSize="30dp"


            />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/pro"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="professional"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/WorldClass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="WorldClass"
            android:textSize="30dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/Legendery"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Legendery"
            android:textSize="30dp" />
    </RadioGroup>


</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="enter your name"
        android:textColor="#3300FF"
        android:textSize="27dp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        />
<EditText
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:id="@+id/nameid"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    />
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/tetrisstartgamebutton"
        android:onClick="start"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dip"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="right|bottom"
    android:orientation="vertical" >


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:onClick="menu"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@drawable/aaaaaa"
        android:id="@+id/BackToTheMenu"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

One reason could be because **Force RTL layout direction** is enabled

So check in device if you have it as enabled (Settings > Developer Options > Force RTL layout direction) and disable it.

[image: look at this]

The cause could be related to RTL o something like that, greetings